# measure issue with custom view with multi-line text

Tags: android, text, canvas

I'm trying to create a custom view for my list items instead of using XML layouts. The view is just a collection of text that I'm drawing to the canvas. Besides a header of fixed size, there's a message body that's multi-line and should resize to fit the width of the list item (minus padding).

The problem is that some item views are either too small or too big, so there's either a lot of white space or text being cut off. I think the issue is with the measuring of the multi-line text in onMeasure.

This is what the view looks like

```
/----------------\
|username    time|
+----------------+
|  multi-line    |
|  message body  |
\----------------/
```

This is the source to the view.

```
class MsgListItem extends View
{
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Bundle data;
    private String username;
    private int gametype;
    private int index;
    private Context cntx;

    final static class Cache
    {
        public static Typeface fontNormal;
        public static Typeface fontItalic;
        public static String username;
        public static int dpi;

        public static void Init(final Context context, final String Username)
        {
            fontNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            fontItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf");
            username = Username;

            final DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            dpi = (int) ((1 + Math.max(metrics.ydpi, metrics.xdpi)) / 160);
        }
    }

    public MsgListItem(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        cntx = context;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTypeface(Cache.fontNormal);
        paint.setTextSize(20 * Cache.dpi);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            // BUG: height is either not enough or too much
        final int height = getTextHeight(data.getString("msg"), width - 32);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height + 45 * Cache.dpi);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
        final int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        // draw msg header
        if (data.getString("username").equals(Cache.username))
            paint.setColor(0xffd2d0ff);
        else
            paint.setColor(0xffcce6ff);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), 30 * Cache.dpi, paint);

        paint.setColor(0xff000000);
        canvas.drawText(data.getString("username"), 8 * Cache.dpi, 22 * Cache.dpi, paint);

        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
        paint.setTypeface(Cache.fontItalic);
        final String time = new PrettyDate(data.getString("time")).agoFormat();
        canvas.drawText(time, width - 8 * Cache.dpi, 22 * Cache.dpi, paint);

        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setTypeface(Cache.fontNormal);

        // draw msg body
        final Bitmap tbit = getTextBitmap(data.getString("msg"), width - 32);
        canvas.drawBitmap(tbit, 16, 30 * Cache.dpi, paint);
    }

    private Bitmap getTextBitmap(final String str, final int width)
    {
        final TextView tv = new TextView(cntx);

        tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
        tv.setText(str);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 22 * Cache.dpi);

        tv.measure(width | MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());

        return tv.getDrawingCache();
    }

    private int getTextHeight(final String str, final int width)
    {
        final TextView tv = new TextView(cntx);

        tv.setText(str);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 22 * Cache.dpi);
        tv.measure(width | MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        return tv.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    public void setData(final Bundle bundle, final int Index)
    {
        data = bundle;
        index = Index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're over-designing this. Is there a reason why you need a custom `View`? It's a lot of work to get right and I'm not seeing any particular benefit in your case. Unless you're just trying to learn how to write a custom view I suppose. If that's the case have at it. Otherwise, I'd just recommend you use something like a `RelativeLayout` with a few `TextView`s inside. It'd make everything much simpler.

As is, you're creating a new TextView every time you measure (bad, but not horrific) and every time you draw (very bad). Once you get past this bug, you're going to see terrible performance out of this, probably including GC thrashing. You're making `TextView` measure and draw for you anyway, why not just use it directly?

If you really want to do your own custom control, I'd cache a [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object and use a combination of [`breakText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20float,%20float%5B%5D%29) and [`FontMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html) to measure and draw.